# Quantity update is not working

Tags: controllers, quantity, multi-vendor, script

We are using following code in file1.phtml page for updating quantity , its working fine.

```
<label class="required" for="qty"><em>*</em><?php echo $helper->__('Quantity')?></label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" value="<?php echo intval($assinproducts->getQty()) ?>" 
class="required-entry validate-zero-or-greater input-text"/>
</div>
```

full code of file1.phtml = > http://pasted.co/7e88d0b2

We are using [This](http://pasted.co/31e1e95a) code in file2.phtml page for updating quantity , its not working. means once we click on update button, it was showing updated value, but once we refresh the page, it was showing old value only.

full code of file2.phtml => http://pasted.co/748ad7ac

so we decided to use code present in file2.phtml in file1.phtml to update quantity, so we are using below code :

**Phtml**

```
<span class="label qty" id="valueqty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>">
        <?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>
    </span>

    <input type="text" id="qty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>"
           onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)"
           name="stock" value="<?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>"
           style="display:none;"/>     

    <span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>">
        <img onclick="showField('<?php echo intval($assinproducts->getQty()) ?>'); return false;"
             src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
    </span>

    <p id="updatedqty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>"
       style="display:none;color:red;">Updated</p><br/>

    <button id="update_button_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>"
            class="button wk_mp_btn1"
            onclick="updateField('<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>',<?php echo intval($assinproducts->getQty()) ?>); return false;"
            style="display:none">
        <span>
            <span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span>
        </span>
    </button>
```

**script**

```
function showField(product_id)
    {
        var qtyId           = '#qty_'+ product_id;
        var editLink        = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
        var updateButton    = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
        var resetButton     = "#reset_button_"+ product_id;

        $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
        $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
        $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
        $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
        $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

        return false;
    }



    function updateField(product_id,assignqty)
    {

        //alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        var qtyId           = '#qty_'+ product_id;
        var valueId         = '#valueqty_'+ product_id;
        var updatedqty      = '#updatedqty_'+ product_id;
        var editLink        = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
        var updateButton    = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
        var resetButton     = "#reset_button"+ product_id;
        var url             = '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateField/')?>';

        $wk_jq(qtyId).toggle();
        $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
        $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
        $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

        $qty = $wk_jq(qtyId).val();
        jQuery(valueId).html($qty);
        hideReset(product_id);

        var tmpQty = assignqty+parseInt($qty) ;
        new Ajax.Request(url, {
            method: 'post',
            parameters: {id: product_id, qty: tmpQty},
            onComplete: function (transport) {
            //  alert(tmpQty);
                jQuery(priceId).val($price);
        jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
                $updateButton.prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    }
```

**controllers.php**

```
public function updateFieldAction(){
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
     echo   $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $selllermpassignproduct=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($id);
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditProductId($id);
         $assignqty=isset($selllermpassignproduct['assignqty'])?$selllermpassignproduct['assignqty']:0;
        $newqty=$this->getRequest()->getParam('qty')+$assignqty;
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
        $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
        $stockItem->setData('qty', $newqty);
        echo $newqty; exit();
        $stockItem->save();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));
      }
```

what i did is instead of `<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>` , i tried `<?php echo intval($assinproducts->getQty()) ?>`

But now when we click edit button, its not working. before when we click on edit button, it was displaying like this :

[image] [image]

Comment: do you have a webpage where we can see what the javascript is doing?

Comment: ok I logged in, now which page?

Comment: same page. can you see product name, you can check any product name there : `ToysBox Think-3` there you can see option to update quanity, but that is not working, once you click on edit button "action" column, you can able to update qty, that is  working.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: what i did is instead of `<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>` , i tried `<?php echo intval($assinproducts->getQty()) ?>` now edit button is not working, do you want me to revert code, so that you can check ?

Comment: ok I see now. looks like js not being called at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38379/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-anja).

Comment: @Anja please check when you are free.....

Comment: I am in the chat waiting for you

Comment: @Anja please check when you are free.....

Comment: it is very specific .. in chat I typed this: the only file I see that is saving the product quantity is the controller.. try to debug that one.. i.e. put some die(); to see what is being passed or if it is called somewhere else

Comment: @BabyinMagento Do you have a live demo?

Comment: @BabyinMagento: Please let me take a look into this controller mpassignproduct/index/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code, hope it helps.

#### Phtml

```
<span class="label qty" id="valueqty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>">
    <?php echo intval($assinproducts->getQty()); ?>
</span>

<input type="text" id="qty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>"
       onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)"
       name="stock" value="<?php echo intval($assinproducts->getQty()); ?>"
       style="display:none;"/>     

<span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>">
    <img onclick="showField('<?php echo intval($assinproducts->getId()) ?>'); return false;"
         src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
</span>

<p id="updatedqty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>"
   style="display:none;color:red;">Updated</p><br/>

<button id="update_button_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>"
        class="button wk_mp_btn1"
        onclick="updateField('<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>',<?php echo intval($assinproducts->getQty()) ?>); return false;"
        style="display:none">
    <span>
        <span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span>
    </span>
</button>
```

#### Controller

```
public function updateFieldAction()
{
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
    $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $selllermpassignproduct = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($productId);
    $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
    $collectionProduct = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$productId))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerId));
    $assignQty = isset($selllermpassignproduct['assignqty']) ? $selllermpassignproduct['assignqty'] : 0;
    $newQty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty') + $assignqty;
    $qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
    $qtyStock->setProductId($id)->setStockId(1);
    $qtyStock->setData('is_in_stock', true); 
    $savedStock = $qtyStock->save();
    $qtyStock->load($savedStock->getId())->setQty($newQty)->save();
    $qtyStock->setProductId($id)->setStockId(1);
    $qtyStock->setData('is_in_stock', true); 
    $savedStock = $qtyStock->save();

    //$stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
    //$stockItem->setData('qty', $newqty);
    //$stockItem->save();

    $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
    //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));
}
```

Comment: i updated your code, now if we click on "edit" button , next to "qty", its not working.

Comment: Change this `showField('<?php echo intval($assinproducts->getId()) ?>');`

Comment: @BabyinMagento I don't see why it's not working. Please double check it.

Comment: i am checking now.

Comment: sorry, its not updating if we click button next to qty