# wrong quantity [zero] is displaying in particular phtml page

Tags: phtml, multi-vendor, qty-increment

we are using following code for updating quantity in file2.phtml file :

[image]

```
<li class="fields">
<div class="customer-name">
<div class="field">
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" value="<?php echo intval($mpAssignProductModel->getQty()) ?>" class="required-entry validate-zero-or-greater input-text"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

i copied this code in file 1, now in file1.phtml page, its displaying like this :

[image]

means correct quantity value [20 ] showing in file2.phtml page , but in file1.phtml page, its showing "0" as quantity

full code for [file1.phtml](http://pasted.co/78c2f52b), [file2.phtml](http://pasted.co/e6eff7a4)

**Edit**

for debug, i used this code : `<?php var_dump($id); ?>` , its displaying `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `$assinproducts` instead of the `$mpAssignProductModel` in the [file1.phtml](http://pasted.co/e6eff7a4). You should add your input with qty after the condition:

```
<?php foreach($this->getCollection() as $assinproducts):  ?>
```

Complete code should looks like this:

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($this->getCollection() as $assinproducts): ?>
    <?php $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($assinproducts->getProductId()); ?>
    <tr class="wk_row_view ">
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" value="<?php echo intval($assinproducts->getQty()) ?>" class="required-entry validate-zero-or-greater input-text"/>
        </td>
....
```

But beware because you can have more than one item in the table. At bottom of the code you can see the original qty input (with id increment in the name) and I strongly recommend you use the original input field:

```
<td>
    <span class="label qty" id="valueqty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>">
        <?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>
    </span>
    <input type="text" id="qty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>"
           onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)"
           name="stock" value="<?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>"
           style="display:none;"/>

    <span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>">
        <img onclick="showField('<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>'); return false;"
             src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
    </span>

    <p id="updatedqty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>"
       style="display:none;color:red;">Updated</p><br/>

    <button id="update_button_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>"
            class="button wk_mp_btn1"
            onclick="updateField('<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>',<?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>); return false;"
            style="display:none">
        <span>
            <span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span>
        </span>
    </button>

    <button id="reset_button_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>"
            type="reset" class="cancel"
            onclick="hideReset('<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>'); return false;"
            style="display:none"></button>
</td>
```

PS: Please tell me if I have mixed files and I will update the answer

Comment: You are genius, for fixing the issue of file 1.phtml page , you updated file2 code. Thanks for your time & patience.

Comment: hi , sorry again, when you are free can you please check my questions : [link1](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109309/display-in-stock-seller-vendor-on-top-of-product-view-page/111007?noredirect=1#comment150721_111007) ,
[link2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107596/display-seller-names-according-to-their-selling-prices) , 
[link3](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100159/quantity-update-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

You have load model using id.

so your code not working

```
$mpAssignProductModel->getQty();
```

Change it to:

```
$mpAssignProductModel->getData('qty');
```

Comment: sorry, it didt worked for me.

Comment: i tried like this : `<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" value="<?php echo intval($mpAssignProductModel->getData('qty')) ?>" class="required-entry validate-zero-or-greater input-text"/>`

Comment: `var_dump($mpAssignProductModel->getData());` check qty field is in it or not?

Comment: displaying `array(0) { }`

Comment: issue is here `<?php $mpAssignProductModel=Mage::getModel("mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct")->load($id); ?>` have no data for particular $id

Comment: than what to do now ?

Comment: Check `mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct` model related table have data or not

Comment: please check here : http://prntscr.com/arbjr6

Comment: above `<?php $mpAssignProductModel=Mage::getModel("mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct")->load($i‌​d); ?>` code var_dump($id); check $id have value or not

Comment: i used this code : `<?php var_dump($id); ?>` , its displaying `NULL`

Comment: In request have no id parameter

Comment: okay, and both files are from same module.

Comment: is there any way  i can fix it ?